# Would like to batch up messages from an application and send as a block

Tags: c#, design-patterns, message

I'm rolling up some simple instrumentation on an desktop windows application, where I would like to write messages about things occurring in the application (possibly on different threads) to a list or queue, then periodically (by time or number of messages) package them up as a json message and forward them to a server.  While I could simply set a timer, and send groups of messages every time it fires, there must be a cleaner way based on some design pattern.  Looking for how this might be handled in a graceful way.  Seems like it might be the observer pattern...

I'm looking for something simple, don't want to set up message queue software or anything like that, going to just pack them up and send them to a web service.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a proper logging framework? e.g. NLog has AsyncWrapper target. You could implement a simple target that sends batches of messages and wrap it in an AsyncWrapper.

Comment: U could use reactive extensions IF you want to do it yourself instead of relying on a logging framework. For RX example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884407/c-sharp-net-buffer-messages-w-timer/42887221#42887221. It shows the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own, you could wrap a list in a class that handles sending messages when there are enough to send.

With the class below, you would just create a global instance of it, then your threads could just call

```
Application.MessageQueue.AddMessage($"{timestamp} - {threadName}: Some message");
```

This is just off the top of my head, but a simplified version of the class would look something like:

```
class MessageQueue
{
    public int MaxQueueSize
    {
        get { return maxQueueSize; }
        set
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                // Setting this to < 1 means messages will not be sent automatically
                // (the calling application must call 'SendMessages' itself)
                if (value < 1) value = int.MaxValue;
                maxQueueSize = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private int maxQueueSize;
    private List<string> unsentMessages;
    private readonly object lockObject = new object();

    public MessageQueue(int maxQueueSize)
    {
        MaxQueueSize = maxQueueSize;
        unsentMessages = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            unsentMessages.Add(message);
        }

        if (unsentMessages.Count >= MaxQueueSize)
        {
            SendMessages();                
        }
    }

    public void SendMessages()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            var messagesToSend = new List<string>();

            while (unsentMessages.Any())
            {
                // Send messages in batches no larger than 'MaxQueueSize'.
                // This allows for dynamic changing of MaxQueueSize, so
                // if it changes from Int.Max to 10, we don't try to send
                // Int.Max messages to the remote server all at once
                messagesToSend = unsentMessages.Take(MaxQueueSize).ToList();
                unsentMessages = unsentMessages.Skip(MaxQueueSize).ToList();

                // Code to send messages to server goes here:
                // RemoteApplication.WebApi.LogMessages(messagesToSend);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message Batch (max {MaxQueueSize} messages):");
                Console.WriteLine($" - {string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine} - ", messagesToSend)}");                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it's helpful at all, here's the simple program I used to test it:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Start message queue with setting to NOT send any messages
    var messageQueue = new MessageQueue(0);
    var cancel = false;

    // First thread sends a message once per second
    var t1 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var counter = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            messageQueue.AddMessage($"{DateTime.Now} - First Thread: message #{counter++}");
            if (cancel) break;
        }
    });

    // Second thread sends a message once every 2 seconds
    var t2 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var counter = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            messageQueue.AddMessage($"{DateTime.Now} - Second Thread: message #{counter++}");
            if (cancel) break;
        }
    });

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();

    int secondsToWait = 10;
    Console.WriteLine($"\nLetting message queue build for {secondsToWait} seconds...");

    // A little progress bar while we're waiting...
    Console.Write(new string((char)9617, secondsToWait));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    while (secondsToWait > 0)
    {
        secondsToWait--;
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Console.Write((char)9619);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Set queue size down to 5
    messageQueue.MaxQueueSize = 5;

    // Cancel when user presses any key
    Console.ReadKey();
    cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer.

Comment: Haha, I see the SO goblins already downvoted my question!

Comment: Ha! Well, I liked it, so +1. ;)  You can mark as answered if you want, but you might want to wait for something better?

Answer (score 0):

consider [Aggregator Pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html).

You can define trigger for sending group of messages based on time or number of messages which are in the group(in order to avoid heavy messages if traffic is high).